# Issue preserving object using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

Having an isue getting JSON to stringify the entire object layout. It currently only stringifies the first object level. If I take the second level, and only stringify that, it works. Though, when I try the entire object, it drops any sublevel proerties.  This is a snippet from a constructor to craet a table instance.

```
var doesTableNameExist,
        dataBase = {
            tables: {}
        },
    _dataBaseInstance,
    _tableInstance = {
        TableName: "",
        Columns: "",
        Rows: "",
        RowCount: ""
    }

    this.TableName = tableName;
    this.Columns = columns;
    this.Rows = rows;
    this.RowCount = 0;

    _dataBaseInstance = localStorage.getItem($config.dataBaseName);
    if (!!_dataBaseInstance)
    {
        dataBase = JSON.parse(_dataBaseInstance);
    }

    doesTableNameExist = dataBase.tables[tableName];

    if (!!doesTableNameExist && !forceNew)
    {
        errorMsg = String.jDBaseFormat("That table name is already used! You cannot have two tables with the name {0}", this.TableName);
        console.error(errorMsg);
    }
    else
    {
        //create the object table and store it after running JSON against it.
        _tableInstance = this;
        dataBase.tables[tableName] = _tableInstance;
        localStorage.setItem($config.dataBaseName, JSON.stringify(dataBase));

        console.log(String.jDBaseFormat("Storing new table '{0}'.", this.TableName));
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  After the stringify process, what the object looks like is:

object ---->  Tables: [];    Not Object --> Tables:  ---->Table instances.

Here is the object during run time.

[image]

So I know the object is all correct. But JSON drops anything in the object property "tables".  Don't understand why.

I also tried it this way:

Yea. I was wondering. It is an instance of the constructor table function.  I tried this, and also no go. I thought it would make it a generic object, and not have the instance attached.

```
_tableInstance = $.extend({}, this);
        dataBase.tables[tableName] = _tableInstance;
        localStorage.setItem($config.dataBaseName, JSON.stringify(dataBase));
```

So I am wondering if I should just return an object, instead of using the "new" constructor for the table, that way I am storing a regular object and not an instance of the constructor?   I will try it out.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: can you reproduce this in a fiddle? i tried, but i'm having issues due to the missing structure around your code

Comment: Yea, give me a moment.

Comment: Actually, I would have to do too much crap to fiddle this instance. I am wondering if it is causing an issue, because it is an instance of a class or an instance, instead of a plain array/object. So, I even tried to take "this"   and use $.extend to create an object replicating the instance of "this", and then make that the table I stringify, but still same outcome.  This is very weird to me.

Comment: I thought stringify with JSON should carry down the entire object model. We use it a lot for my application at my company I develop, and we handle multiple level objects just fine.  So, wonder why this object isn't being treated very nice by JSON.stringify....  lol  :(

Comment: well, if it's not just a plain object, that's likely why you're having problems. json can't represent anything more than a plain object/array..

Comment: I tried using a regular object, instead of an instance of the Constructor Function, and still no go.  I am going to give it a while, and then come back to this. I feel I am overlooking something basic.

Comment: One more note. It is strange that when I stringify the dataBsase object, it only works down until the tables property. So I thought maybe my tables objects were causing a problem. But, when I stringify "dataBase.tables" it correctly modifies it. So weird that it cannot handle entire object.

Comment: There are constructors / function calls with in the objects. I then see that this was killing it. :( Sad me... Sad Sad me.... I guess I will only attach the table data, and not the instances of it, and then have to reapply the instances to the types [table], [row], etc when pulling the data back out. Thanks again @Kevin B., for opening my damn eyes to the obvious, that I was over looking.. lol